# GET UUID from PUBNUB hereNOW() using Pubnub V4

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I am trying to retrieve UUIDs of devices connected to 'my_channel'.
I was using pubnub-3.16.4.js and I was able to get the UUID array using "Here Now".

Now I upgraded to pubnub.4.1.1.js, I followed the example on this site
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/presence-sdk-v4
when I use Here Now function I do get a response, which includes all state and UUIDs information.

```
Object {totalChannels: 1, totalOccupancy: 2, channels: Object}
channels:Object
    mychannel:Object
        name:"my_channel"
        occupancy:2
        occupants:Array[3]
            0:  Object
                state:null
                uuid:"000000003d425f88"
            __proto__:Object
            1:  Object
                state:null
                uuid:"newmanager" ......................
```

But what I need is only UUID array, which the sdk example shows.

Any idea how get only UUID array, or is there an easy way to retrieve the UUIDs from the above response?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry to hijack your question, but can you currently get to pubnub.com? I can't and I've tried a couple DNS tools online that say it has problems. Just trying to confirm.

Comment: Related, can you just use `response.channels.mychannel.occupants[0].uuid`?

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Presence Here Now - without state data

```js
pubnub.hereNow(
    {
        channels: ["ch1"], 
        includeUUIDs: true,
        includeState: false
    },
    function (status, response) {
        // handle status, response
    }
);
```

See full [Node SDK hereNow docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs/api-reference-sdk-v4#here_now_args_1) for full parameter details and sample code.